# If we set Firefox profile for parent window, will that be carry forwarded to child window when we use "driver.switchTo().window(child window Id)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a doubt in case of parent and child window handling. If we set Firefox profile for parent window, will that be carry forwarded to child window when we use "driver.switchTo().window(child window Id) " or we need to explicitly set the profile explicitly once again.

One more doubt is ..... Will the profile be reassigned to parent when we do driver.switchTo().window(Parent window Id) ?

Thanks,
Raje

Comment: Hi all, I got the solution......   I set the profile for the parent window as i was suppose to download the files to specific folder. Once i set the profile i used the driver.getWindowHandles to get all the window ids instatiated by that parent window. Once i got the child window id, used driver.switchTo.window(child ID). In a child window i had link to download a file. when i clicked on the link the files were downloading to specific folder. This shows that the child window will have the same profile as the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You need to use name or window handle for switching back and forth to newly opened window. See [this](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#window%28java.lang.String%29)

In terms of *windowHandles* You have to find them runtime since those are dynamically generated. The window handles will not be same every time. So saving them into profiler will not help.

On the other hand, if you need to deal with only the parent window then there is no need to do anything with window handles or something similar. Selenium by default deal with Parent window.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox profile set for parent window will not carry forward to child windows when we switch to the child window. This answers your first part of question.

Actually, Window is switched using the getWindowHandle() method, which return a handle that uniquely identifies it within the driver instance. If you look at the method defination, it return a String and the Profile do not get forwarded.

> public java.lang.String getWindowHandle()

Secondly, we cannot explicitly set the Profile once again as Profile are set before the WebDriver is initialized. The child window will use the Profile that has been set for that window.  When switched to parent window there will be no change in profile of that window. This answers the second part.

Browser Profiles are something that cannot be changed for WebDrivers after the Driver is initialized using that Profile. Hence, Windows of different Drivers will have the corresponding profiles set for them and cannot be reassigned afterwards.